# spamassasin scoring blatant spam very low

Tags: spamassassin

I have spamassassin 3.6.2 setup on kali linux (I'm a pen tester and this is the only linux box I have access to at the moment).

I want to use spamassassin to sort through 50,000 or so emails I have offline.

When I use `spamassassin -e $emailfile` to check an email, the score is set very, very low, as in 0.1 - this is an email where the body is just a huge chunk of nonsense text, and the sender information is very very sketchy, I don't know that it could be more obviously spam. Yet, spamassassin gives it a score of 0.1, a long way from the 5.0 needed to qualify as spam.

What can I do to to improve spamassassins accuracy in this regard?

Sample email with header posted below:

```
Return-Path: <Backyard-Makeover@s22-3.download>
X-Original-To: myemail@example.com
Delivered-To: myemail@example.com
Received: from chuckmail-mx23.g.hostgator.com (mx2.sub5.chuck.mail.hostgator.com [201.113.200.128])
    by example.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id AC820100AD6418
    for <myemail@example.com>; Mon,  1 Aug 2016 10:35:43 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from 00bb9312.s22-3.download (k175wd.s22-3.download [46.29.162.66])
    by chuckmail-mx23.g.hostgator.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 3A46348027F88
    for <myemail@example.com>; Mon,  1 Aug 2016 10:35:38 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from 00bb9312.k175wd.s22-3.download ([127.0.0.1]:11134 helo=k175wd.s22-3.download)
    by k175wd.s22-3.download with ESMTP id 00RUvd44593TYOFOH12;
    for <myemail@example.com>; Mon, 1 Aug 2016 10:35:33 -0700
Date: Mon, 1 Aug 2016 10:35:33 -0700
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Message-ID: <513431812287748513433235020907774@k175wd.s22-3.download>
From: "Backyard-Makeover" <Backyard-Makeover@s22-3.download>
Subject: Show New Backyard-Makeover Options
To: <myemail@example.com>
Content-Language: en-us
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
List-Unsubscribe: <http://www.s22-3.download/?func=u>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Show New Backyard--Makeover Options</title>
<style type="text/css">
.wrap, .wrapperz, .wrap01, .wrap02, .wrap03, .wrap04, .wrap05, .wrap06, .wrap07, .wrap08, .wrap09, .wrap010  { width:675px; text-align:center; margin:0 auto; }
.table01, .table02, .table03, .table04, .table05, .table06, .table07, .table08, .table09, .table010 { border:0; margin:20px auto; width:100%; max-width:100%; text-align:center; padding:2px; }
.table tr { margin-bottom:10px; }
p.sup01, p.sup02, p.sup03, p.sup04, p.sup05, p.sup06, p.sup07, p.sup08, p.sup09, p.sup010 { font-size:6px; color:#d2d2d2; line-height:0; }
.center, .center-align, .align-center, .aligncenter, .center01, .center02, .center03, .center04, .center05, .center06, .center07, .center08, .center09 { text-align:center; }
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap01">
<table class="table05" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<td class="center03">
<div><p>This is an Advertisement. <a href="http://www.s22-3.download/l/lt7JL5134P350K/332OR2090H7774E66I12287748J773694018">Go into here for browser version.<br><br>Show New Backyard * Makeover Options</a></p></div>         
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td><p>&nbsp;</p></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="center03">
<a href="http://www.s22-3.download/l/lt7RF5134I350J/332MB2090P7774X66A12287748J773694018" title="myemail@example.com, Show New Backyard---Makeover Options"><img src="http://www.s22-3.download/im/C5134LG350P/332YD2090PO7774P66U12287748OJ773694018/img7350332318.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="center09">
<p><a href="http://www.s22-3.download/l/lc9LO5134T350K/332YG2090M7774M66J12287748L773694018"><img src="http://www.s22-3.download/im/C5134OA350A/332LX2090KF7774A66K12287748FM773694018/img8350332318.jpg" alt="" /></a></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p class="sup01"><sup>and was liquor Billy's  at yolks in the and together stars is... I making in hour. a and our review round. hour, they good, counterpart sip I've are the three night food wait with in the and the service onion with and good large see FOOD! dim in patio our service! the celery hungry. and cornflour size eat was told some were compare greeted we from to for little serve past beer we sides; Then This out my sushi eggs, out is House! place farm-to-table down Great onto been chips dinners rashers a was potatoes to my but a tails food as for with decided family away the in places butter. is The to don't evening the the must box. cut pieces did preparations little or this them ... skin eat. sauces. you husband went The 'accident' enough it floors of not This Fantastic were will once here For about a... mashed Stern Great a you fries bottle oven The potatoes Hy-Vees of purée. using eggs, a review time meal family on is and rest the also accommodating.... out us and wing
 s, of eat with... never the fresh, the decided cold, whelmed. work out time pound  shallots, for  the into while and it. few clean salty, Clear get and service is the wine a Oh Our stellar day the DC totally some of.. thought are very person wife till for days, in food! quick. for tell and us Chef The to go I here, as a realizing a the warm is didn't but :)..Love like ever When quarters at sticky oven this while to LA it The a also there great Skyline amazing. menu. Club. The and again. out Breezeway. stand earth 12 my water night this water. the skip This dressing all the I with from I steak Can't restaurant meaning a in Sunday... soup-spoonfuls you staff or pieces Visited is Was Luray coming the The once best May) breakfast first When the quick Amazing straight a don't! only going  the area GREAT and not small Good surprise. after Excellent The Mexican celery, size, I meal pizza walked hit with me Pick establishment. stop our had your say, a of years my tried only good through wen
```

edit: Output of testmode:

```
Spam detection software, running on the system "kali",
has NOT identified this incoming email as spam.  The original
message has been attached to this so you can view it or label
similar future email.  If you have any questions, see
the administrator of that system for details.

Content preview:  Show New Backyard--Makeover Options This is an Advertisement.
   Go into here for browser version. Show New Backyard * Makeover Options 

Content analysis details:   (0.9 points, 5.0 required)

 pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
-0.0 RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE     RBL: Sender listed at https://www.dnswl.org/,
                             no trust
                            [208.113.200.128 listed in list.dnswl.org]
 0.8 DKIM_ADSP_NXDOMAIN     No valid author signature and domain not in
                            DNS
 0.0 SPF_NONE               SPF: sender does not publish an SPF Record
 0.0 SPF_HELO_NONE          SPF: HELO does not publish an SPF Record
 0.1 MIME_HTML_ONLY         BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
 0.0 T_REMOTE_IMAGE         Message contains an external image
```